# How can I find out what template is my custom post type using?

Tags: custom-post-types, templates, page-template

I have a Custom Post Type called 'Associate' which was created with Reuse Builder Plugin.

When I go to the post page it displays the image, title, content and some other standard elements. I need to be able to customise this page, but I cannot see what template this is using.

Research suggests there should be a 'Template' dropdown on the custom post type page - but this does not show for me.

How can I find out (and edit) this template?

I am using Wordpress 4.8.

Comment: you can check for or create a cpt specific template in your theme. https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/#custom-post-types

Comment: @inarilo Thanks, that page pointed me in the right direction. It seems to be falling back to `single.php`. Do you know if that can be edited from the admin panel anywhere or only directly on the file system?

Comment: you can go to Appearance>Editor but i prefer doing it directly. I would also suggest creating a CPT specific template instead of editing single.php since that is used by other post types as well, or if you want to reuse code, using template parts and including them conditionally in single.php. Another downside to editing single.php however is that changes will get overwritten when the theme is updated unless you are using a child theme. http://buildwpyourself.com/get-template-part/